# ¿Como generar un total distinto por fila?

Tags: angularjs

Yo tengo el siguiente código:

```
 <td ng-repeat="actividad in actividades | filter:{circular_id: puntuacion.circular_id, tipo_a_id: 1}">
    <span ng-repeat="puntuacion in puntuaciones | filter:{club_id: club.id, 
    actividad_id: actividad.id}" ng-bind="puntuacion.puntos || 0" ng-
    init="total(puntuacion, club)"></span>
 </td>
```

Con `ng-init="total(puntuacion, club)"`, quiero generar el total de puntos por fila, es decir por club.

La función total es la siguiente:

```
$scope.total = function(puntuacion, club){
  if(puntuacion.club_id == club.id){
     $scope.total[club.id] += (puntuacion.puntos);
  }
}
```

Esta función me genera es el ultimo valor que tiene cada club y no la suma de cada uno de ellos.

Miren el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor de antemano les agradezgo su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que te refieres a que cada fila es un club distinto, no?
Creo que el problema está en que guardas el total de las puntuaciones en una misma variable para todos y cada fila/club debería tener un propio contador.

Una posible solución seria pasarle un parámetro más (`$index`) a la función total, algo así:

```html
<td ng-repeat="actividad in actividades | filter:{circular_id: puntuacion.circular_id, tipo_a_id: 1}" ng-init="teamIndex = $index">
    <span ng-repeat="puntuacion in puntuaciones | filter:{club_id: club.id, 
    actividad_id: actividad.id}" ng-bind="puntuacion.puntos || 0" ng-
    init="total(puntuacion, teamIndex)"></span>
 </td>
```

```
$scope.total = function(puntuacion, indice){
  if(puntuacion){
    $scope.total[indice] += (puntuacion.puntos);
  }
}
```

Comment: se ve bien, lo voy a probar!

Comment: oye me da 0 :( sabrás porque?

Comment: Acomodare la pregunta de acuerdo a otra cosa que probé, si puedes ayudarme fino